# Replace data with python Excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have two excel sheets. One with formula and one without. Now I want to get the data from the Excel Sheet with Formula and replace it.

```
data_read_only = list()
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
ws = wb['Abschätzung SD Intern ']

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        data_read_only.append(cell.value)




wb: Workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=False)
ws: Worksheet = wb['Abschätzung SD Intern ']

for element in data_read_only:
    print(element)
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            ws.cell(row=row, column=cell).value = element

wb.save(filename)
```

How can I replace the rows?

Answer (score 0):

For reading values from file and storing, it may be more intuitive to use a list of lists to store cell values like this:

```
data_read_only = list()
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    cell_list = []
    for cell in row:
        cell_list.append(cell.value)
    data_read_only.append(cell_list)
```

For my test file which had 6 rows and 2 columns, the resulting `data_read_only` content was:

```
>>> data_read_only
[['Num', 'Factor'], [1, 5], [2, 10], [3, 15], [4, 20], [5, 25]]
```

For the overwriting part, it gets easier with this list of lists whose row and column indices are obtained by enumeration. The corresponding cell is then assigned the value from `data_read_only` using those indices as follows:

```
wb_form = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=False)
ws_form = wb_form['Sheet1']

for r_index,row in enumerate(ws_form.iter_rows()):
    for c_index,cell in enumerate(row):
        ws_form[cell.column_letter+str(cell.row)] = data_read_only[r_index][c_index]

wb_form.save(filename)
```